# Problema de compatibilidade do jQuery1.7.2 para o jQuery 3.3.1

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, script

Sou leigo em `JS`, mas preciso de uma aplicação urgente e achei uma que me atende, só fazer as adaptações. Tenho o seguinte código abaixo:

```js
function id( el ){
        //return document.getElementById( el );
        return $( el );
}
function calcTotal( un01, qnt01 )
{
        return un01 * qnt01;
}
function getElementParent(event){
    return event.srcElement.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute('id');
}
function getValorUnitario(elParent){
    return $('#'+elParent+' .class_unit input').val();
}
function getQuantidade(elParent){
    return $('#'+elParent+' .class_quant input').val();
}
function setFieldTotal(elParent, valueUnit, valueQuant){
    id('#'+elParent+' .class_total input').val(calcTotal( valueUnit , valueQuant));
    setTotalFinal();
}
function setTotalFinal(){
    
    var total = 0;
    $('#table-shop tr .class_total input').each(function(){
        if(this.value != ''){
        var valor = this.value;
        total += parseInt(valor);
        }
    });
    $('#total .value_total').html(total);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
        id('#table-shop tr .class_unit').keyup(function(event)
        {
            var elemenPai = getElementParent(event);
            var valueUnit = getValorUnitario(elemenPai);
            var valueQuant = getQuantidade(elemenPai);

            setFieldTotal(elemenPai, valueUnit , valueQuant);
        });      
       
        id('#table-shop tr .class_quant').keyup(function(event)
        {
            var elemenPai = getElementParent(event);
            var valueUnit = getValorUnitario(elemenPai);
            var valueQuant = getQuantidade(elemenPai);

            setFieldTotal(elemenPai, valueUnit , valueQuant);
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" ></script>

<form action="" method="post">
            <table id="table-shop">
                <tr id="line1">
                    <td class="class_unit">Valor Unitário 01:<input type="text" name="valor_unitario01" id="valor_unitario01" /></td>
                    <td class="class_quant">Quantidade: <input type="text" name="qnt01" id="qnt01" value="0" /></td>
                    <td class="class_total">Total: <input type="text" name="total01" id="total01" readonly="readonly" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr id="line2">
                    <td class="class_unit">Valor Unitário 02:<input type="text" name="valor_unitario02" id="valor_unitario02" /></td>
                    <td class="class_quant">Quantidade: <input type="text" name="qnt02" id="qnt02" value="0" /></td>
                    <td class="class_total">Total: <input type="text" name="total02" id="total02" readonly="readonly" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr id="line3">
                    <td class="class_unit">Valor Unitário 03:<input type="text" name="valor_unitario03" id="valor_unitario03" /></td>
                    <td class="class_quant">Quantidade: <input type="text" name="qnt03" id="qnt03" value="0" /></td>
                    <td class="class_total">Total: <input type="text" name="total03" id="total03" readonly="readonly" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr id="line4">
                    <td class="class_unit">Valor Unitário 04:<input type="text" name="valor_unitario04" id="valor_unitario04" /></td>
                    <td class="class_quant">Quantidade: <input type="text" name="qnt04" id="qnt04" value="0" /></td>
                    <td class="class_total">Total: <input type="text" name="total04" id="total04" readonly="readonly" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr id="line5">
                    <td class="class_unit">Valor Unitário 05:<input type="text" name="valor_unitario05" id="valor_unitario05" /></td>
                    <td class="class_quant">Quantidade: <input type="text" name="qnt05" id="qnt05" value="0" /></td>
                    <td class="class_total">Total: <input type="text" name="total05" id="total05" readonly="readonly" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div id="total">Total: <span class="value_total"></span> </div>
    <div id="total">Total: <input class="value_total" readonly>
</div>
</form>
```

Porém, se eu usar o `jQuery 3.3.1` ele dá esse erro:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined"

Se eu usar o `jQuery 1.7.2` funciona! Se eu colocar a seguinte referencia:

```
script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js" /script
script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" /script
```

Obs.: tirei as `<` `>` acima, para ser possível fazer a citação aqui.

também não funciona. Alguém pode me ajudar, por favor?

Fonte do código: https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/519699-multiplicar-quantidade-por-pre%C3%A7o-e-exibir-no-total/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mas qual seria o problema em usar jQuery 1.7.2?
Enfim, rodando o código no debugger é possível verificar que o  jQuery 3.3.1 te dá uma referência ao elemento em que está o event listener via propriedade `target` ao invés de `srcElement`.

Então bastaria refatorar a função getElementParent para

```
function getElementParent(event){
    return event.target.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute('id');
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! resolveu o meu problema, batava a modificação sugerida acima.