# Adicionar ou Remover Inputs com JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

tenho uma dúvida?! no link abaixo:

[Problema de compatibilidade do jQuery1.7.2 para o jQuery 3.3.1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/363448/problema-de-compatibilidade-do-jquery1-7-2-para-o-jquery-3-3-1)

eu tenho um código que me calcula algumas inputs com base no preço, quantidade, subtotal (preço * quantidade) e total geral (soma dos subtotais das inputs), conforme exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acontece que eu gostaria de esconder todas as inputs e ir mostrando conforme eu clicar em um botão, para adicionar novos produtos (*inputs*). Eu fiz com base no projeto:

[Adicionar / remover campos dinamicamente](https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/325267-resolvido-adicionar-remover-campos-dinamicamente/)

Porém, como as inputs são geradas no JS eu não consegui fazer funcionar.
Alguém poderia me ajudar? É possível?

Segue meu exemplo:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js" ></script>

<form name="form1" action="" method="post">

<script type="text/javascript">
//Total máximo de campos que você permitirá criar em seu site:
var totalCampos = 10;

//Não altere os valores abaixo, pois são variáveis controle;
var iLoop = 1;
var iCount = 0;
var linhaAtual;


function AddCampos() {
var hidden1 = document.getElementById("hidden1");
var hidden2 = document.getElementById("hidden2");

//Executar apenas se houver possibilidade de inserção de novos campos:
if (iCount < totalCampos) {

//Limpar hidden1, para atualizar a lista dos campos que ainda estão vazios:
hidden2.value = "";

//Atualizando a lista dos campos que estão ocultos.
//Essa lista ficará armazenada temporiariamente em hidden2;
for (iLoop = 1; iLoop <= totalCampos; iLoop++) {
        if (document.getElementById("linha"+iLoop).style.display == "none") {
                if (hidden2.value == "") {
                        hidden2.value = "linha"+iLoop;
                }else{
                        hidden2.value += ",linha"+iLoop;
                }
        }
}
//Quebrando a lista que foi armazenada em hidden2 em array:

linhasOcultas = hidden2.value.split(",");


        if (linhasOcultas.length > 0) {
                //Tornar visível o primeiro elemento de linhasOcultas:
                document.getElementById(linhasOcultas[0]).style.display = "block"; iCount++;
                
                //Acrescentando o índice zero a hidden1:
                if (hidden1.value == "") {
                        hidden1.value = linhasOcultas[0];
                }else{
                        hidden1.value += ","+linhasOcultas[0];
                }
                
                /*Retirar a opção acima da lista de itens ocultos: <-------- OPCIONAL!!!
                if (hidden2.value.indexOf(","+linhasOcultas[0]) != -1) {
                        hidden2.value = hidden2.value.replace(linhasOcultas[0]+",","");
                }else if (hidden2.indexOf(linhasOcultas[0]+",") == 0) {
                        hidden2.value = hidden2.value.replace(linhasOcultas[0]+",","");
                }else{
                        hidden2.value = "";
                }
                */
        }
}
}

function RemoverCampos(id) {
//Criando ponteiro para hidden1:        
var hidden1 = document.getElementById("hidden1");

//Pegar o valor do campo que será excluído:
var campoValor = document.getElementById("valor_unitario"+id).value;
        //Se o campo não tiver nenhum valor, atribuir a string: vazio:
        if (campoValor == "") {
                campoValor = "vazio";
        }

     if(confirm("O campo que contém o valor:\n» "+campoValor+"\nserá excluído!\n\nDeseja prosseguir?")){
                document.getElementById("linha"+id).style.display = "none"; iCount--;
                
                //Removendo o valor de hidden1:
                if (hidden1.value.indexOf(",linha"+id) != -1) {
                        hidden1.value = hidden1.value.replace(",linha"+id,"");
                }else if (hidden1.value.indexOf("linha"+id+",") == 0) {
                        hidden1.value = hidden1.value.replace("linha"+id+",","");
                }else{
                        hidden1.value = "";
                }
        }
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function id( el ){
        //return document.getElementById( el );
        return $( el );
}
function calcTotal( un01, qnt01 )
{
        return un01 * qnt01;
}
function getElementParent(event){
    return event.srcElement.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute('id');
}
function getValorUnitario(elParent){
    return $('#'+elParent+' .class_unit input').val();
}
function getQuantidade(elParent){
    return $('#'+elParent+' .class_quant input').val();
}
function setFieldTotal(elParent, valueUnit, valueQuant){
    id('#'+elParent+' .class_total input').val(calcTotal( valueUnit , valueQuant));
    setTotalFinal();
}
function setTotalFinal(){
    
    var total = 0;
    $('#table-shop div .class_total input').each(function(){
        if(this.value != ''){
        var valor = this.value;
        total += parseInt(valor);
        }
    });
    $('#total .value_total').html(total);
    $('#total .value_total').val(total);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
        id('#table-shop div .class_unit').keyup(function(event)
        {
            var elemenPai = getElementParent(event);
            var valueUnit = getValorUnitario(elemenPai);
            var valueQuant = getQuantidade(elemenPai);

            setFieldTotal(elemenPai, valueUnit , valueQuant);
        });      
       
        id('#table-shop div .class_quant').keyup(function(event)
        {
            var elemenPai = getElementParent(event);
            var valueUnit = getValorUnitario(elemenPai);
            var valueQuant = getQuantidade(elemenPai);

            setFieldTotal(elemenPai, valueUnit , valueQuant);
        });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//Escrevendo o código-fonte HTML e ocultando os campos criados:
for (iLoop = 1; iLoop <= totalCampos; iLoop++) {
        document.write("<span id='linha"+iLoop+"' style='display:none'><div class='class_unit'>Valor Unitário "+iLoop+":<input type='text' name='valor_unitario"+iLoop+"' id='valor_unitario"+iLoop+"' /></div><div class='class_quant'>Quantidade "+iLoop+": <input type='text' name='qnt"+iLoop+"' id='qnt"+iLoop+"' value='0' /></div><div class='class_total'>SubTotal "+iLoop+": <input type='text' name='total"+iLoop+"' id='total"+iLoop+"' readonly='readonly' /></div> <input type='button' value='Remover' onclick='RemoverCampos(\""+iLoop+"\")'></span>");
}
</script>

 <div id="total">Total: <span class="value_total"></span> </div>
 <div id="total">Total: <input class="value_total" readonly></input> </div>

    <br><br><br>

 <input type="button" value="Adicionar campos" onclick="AddCampos()">
 <br><br><input type="text" name="hidden1" id="hidden1">
 <input type="hidden" name="hidden2" id="hidden2">


</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Acontece que consigo mostrar/esconder as *inputs*, porém não calcula!
Agradeço muito.

Comment: Poderia adicionar o seu código na pergunta? Pode utilizar o snippet (botão `</>` do editor) para mostrar funcionando.

Comment: Se você disponibilizar o código fica mais fácil de encontrar o problema

Comment: Pela Lógica do que precisa, Valor unitário, quantidade e subtotal precisa ser feito via javascript?
Tu poderia pensar em deixar esses inputs fixos para preenchimento e passar o valor preenchido para o novo campo quando submetido e então após cada submição é calculado o total e caso o total é zero nada aparece e outras condições podem ser feitas, caso não tenha Valor uniario não aparece quantidade nem subtotal e quando quantidade é 0 não aparece subtotal.

Comment: Então...esse é um sistema de serviços de auto mecânica, e conforme vai colocando as peças a serem usada, o sistema já vai calculando. nesse caso preciso acompanhar quão caro vai ficando a 'compra' para poder repassar para o cliente ou revisar algum item, antes de fechar a ordem de produção e dar baixa no sistema. Aceito alguma sugestão!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É só criar uma função que faz os cálculos e chamá-la quando você adiciona ou remove linhas. A função irá calcular os valores dos inputs visíveis e colocar os subtotais nos respectivos campos e o total geral no campo dele.

Veja abaixo que criei uma função `calcula()` que percorre todas as linhas visíveis fazendo os cálculos. Foi preciso também fazer várias alterações no código, resultando num código bem mais enxuto e legível do que o anterior:

```js
function calcula(){
   
   var total = 0;
   $("span[id^=linha]:visible").each(function(){
      
      var val_unit = parseFloat($(".class_unit input", this).val().replace(",", "."));
      var qnt = $(".class_quant input", this).val();
      var sub_total = val_unit * qnt;

      if(!isNaN(sub_total)) $(".class_total input", this).val(sub_total.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
      
      total += parseFloat($("input[id^=total]", this).val().replace(",", "."));

   });

   if(!isNaN(total)) $("#total input.value_total").val(total.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
   
}


//Total máximo de campos que você permitirá criar em seu site:
var totalCampos = 10;

//Não altere os valores abaixo, pois são variáveis controle;
var iLoop = 1;
var iCount = 0;
var linhaAtual;


function AddCampos() {
   var hidden1 = document.getElementById("hidden1");
   var hidden2 = document.getElementById("hidden2");

   //Executar apenas se houver possibilidade de inserção de novos campos:
   if (iCount < totalCampos) {

      //Limpar hidden1, para atualizar a lista dos campos que ainda estão vazios:
      hidden2.value = "";

      //Atualizando a lista dos campos que estão ocultos.
      //Essa lista ficará armazenada temporiariamente em hidden2;
      for (iLoop = 1; iLoop <= totalCampos; iLoop++) {
         if (document.getElementById("linha"+iLoop).style.display == "none") {
            if (hidden2.value == "") {
               hidden2.value = "linha"+iLoop;
            }else{
               hidden2.value += ",linha"+iLoop;
            }
         }
      }
      //Quebrando a lista que foi armazenada em hidden2 em array:

      linhasOcultas = hidden2.value.split(",");


      if (linhasOcultas.length > 0) {
         //Tornar visível o primeiro elemento de linhasOcultas:
         document.getElementById(linhasOcultas[0]).style.display = "block"; iCount++;
      
         //Acrescentando o índice zero a hidden1:
         if (hidden1.value == "") {
            hidden1.value = linhasOcultas[0];
         }else{
            hidden1.value += ","+linhasOcultas[0];
         }
      
         /*Retirar a opção acima da lista de itens ocultos: <-------- OPCIONAL!!!
         if (hidden2.value.indexOf(","+linhasOcultas[0]) != -1) {
         hidden2.value = hidden2.value.replace(linhasOcultas[0]+",","");
         }else if (hidden2.indexOf(linhasOcultas[0]+",") == 0) {
         hidden2.value = hidden2.value.replace(linhasOcultas[0]+",","");
         }else{
         hidden2.value = "";
         }
         */
         calcula();
      }
   }
}

function RemoverCampos(id) {
   //Criando ponteiro para hidden1:        
   var hidden1 = document.getElementById("hidden1");

   //Pegar o valor do campo que será excluído:
   var campoValor = document.getElementById("valor_unitario"+id).value;
   //Se o campo não tiver nenhum valor, atribuir a string: vazio:
   if (campoValor == "") {
      campoValor = "vazio";
   }

   if(confirm("O campo que contém o valor:\n» "+campoValor+"\nserá excluído!\n\nDeseja prosseguir?")){
      document.getElementById("linha"+id).style.display = "none"; iCount--;
   
      //Removendo o valor de hidden1:
      if (hidden1.value.indexOf(",linha"+id) != -1) {
         hidden1.value = hidden1.value.replace(",linha"+id,"");
      }else if (hidden1.value.indexOf("linha"+id+",") == 0) {
         hidden1.value = hidden1.value.replace("linha"+id+",","");
      }else{
         hidden1.value = "";
      }
      
      calcula();
   }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('span[id^=linha] input').on("input", calcula);
});

//Escrevendo o código-fonte HTML e ocultando os campos criados:
for (iLoop = 1; iLoop <= totalCampos; iLoop++) {
   document.write("<span id='linha"+iLoop+"' style='display:none'><div class='class_unit'>Valor Unitário "+iLoop+":<input type='text' name='valor_unitario"+iLoop+"' id='valor_unitario"+iLoop+"' /></div><div class='class_quant'>Quantidade "+iLoop+": <input type='text' name='qnt"+iLoop+"' id='qnt"+iLoop+"' value='0' /></div><div class='class_total'>SubTotal "+iLoop+": <input type='text' name='total"+iLoop+"' id='total"+iLoop+"' readonly='readonly' /></div> <input type='button' value='Remover' onclick='RemoverCampos(\""+iLoop+"\")'></span>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js" ></script>
<form name="form1" action="" method="post">

   <div id="total">Total: <input class="value_total" readonly></input> </div>
   <br><br><br>
   <input type="button" value="Adicionar campos" onclick="AddCampos()">
   <br><br><input type="text" name="hidden1" id="hidden1">
   <input type="hidden" name="hidden2" id="hidden2">

</form>
```

Comment: Exatamente isso! vou estudar o funcionamento antes de implementar, para poder aprender e não copiar ;). Tem alguma sugestão de leitura sobre JS? Agradeço a atenção.

Comment: A W3S tem um bom material pra inciante.