# Arrays com chaves que variam numericamente

Tags: php, array

No `PHP` estou declarando a minha variável assim:

```
$id_produto = $dados["id_produto".$input.""];
```

Onde `$inc` é incremento dentro do laço e o `$dados["id_produto".$input.""]` deveria retornar algo como `$dados["id_produto1"]`, `$dados["id_produto2"]` ...

É correto declarar a variável desse jeito?

Comment: **errado** seria uma palavra forte... Mas eu acho que você poderia gerar um array multidimensional. Assim:  `$produtos[0]["id_produto"] = 1` ... `$produtos[0]["nome"] = "panela"`... `$produtos[1]["id_produto"] = 2` ... `$produtos[1]["nome"] = "prato"`

Comment: Mas tudo depende do que você pretende fazer...

Comment: então... é que na minha aplicação eu tenho diversas inputs com a id: id_produtoN... e vou pegar o valor de cada id desses e jogar dentro de um while, portento teria algo como $id_produto = $dados["id_produto".$input.""];
A partir dai faria uma consulta

Comment: esse $id_produto = $dados["id_produto".$input.""]; teria que me retornar algo como:
$id_produto = id_produto1 <== relacionando ao valor da input 1 e assim por diante

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso está errado, ou pelo menos é gambiarra, se tem uma outra dimensão de dados, então deveria criar esta dimensão, algo assim:

```
$dados["id_produto"][$input];
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Array/MultiDimentional2.php).

Note que só o elemento identificado por `"id_produto"` teria essa dimensão adicional.

Não é que não possa fazer em hipótese alguma, mas é o mecanismo errado de programação. Já seria só meio errado, ou talvez certo, se o índice final nunca fosse usado como variável.

Comment: Obrigado! Isso -> $dados["id_produto"][$input]; -> seria meio certo? Não é usual?
O correto mesmo seria eu já passar o id_produtoN já 'pronto', de uma input, span, etc.?

Comment: @Nosredna não... O "certo", ou o "mais certo" seria fazer algo parecido como o Maniero sugeriu. A forma como você faz na pergunta é que não é o usual.

Comment: @Nosredna eu não digo que é errado, pois você pode ter um motivo bom para fazer desta forma, apesar de eu não conseguir enxergar isso na sua pergunta.

Comment: @Andrei Coelho Obrigado! a minha aplicação é similar do link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/363811/adicionar-ou-remover-inputs-com-js/363855?noredirect=1#comment726430_363855
Eu tenho inputs adicionadas dinamicamente, e as id's destas são colocadas em uma  input do tipo hidden, para serem passadas para validação. Acontece que além dessas inputs id_nome1, id_nome2, id_nomeN eu ainda tenho id_idade1, id_idadeN e para não colocar todas dentro da hidden eu tentei essa outra alternativa.